# How to find the frequency of a pattern in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, pattern-matching

Consider a list (`list`) as

```
list = {{0, 0, 0, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 2, 
   0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1}};
```

In matrix form:

[image]

I wish to find the frequency and position of all the occurrence of the pattern `0, 1`along the horizontal direction. i.e.

[image]

I also wish to find the same pattern in the vertical direction as well as shown below:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: You could do something like `Total[SequenceCount[#, {0, 1}] & /@ list]` and `Total[SequenceCount[#, {0, 1}] & /@ Transpose[list]]` for the horizontal and vertical counts.

Comment: @J.M. Very nice solution. In short then: `Map[ SequenceCount[#, {0, 1}] &, 
  list~Join~(list\[Transpose])] // Total`.

Comment: Is there a reason for not counting 4 appearances in your first example and 9 appearances in the second?

Comment: @gwr, joining the matrix and its transpose might be risky if the `0, 1` pattern shows up at the seam; it will get counted even if it shouldn't be.

Comment: On the last image the ordering is mixing vertical and horizontal pairs. Is that an ordering that matters?

Comment: @Coolwater The ordering doesn't matter. It's just for illustration.

Comment: @J.M. Cannot see why joining should be a problem since we are mapping over the sublists at the first level? Where should seams be in the way?

Comment: @gwr, ah; I didn't immediately notice that you were only mapping over rows; you are right, of course, and my fears were baseless after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This gives a list of two lists. The first contains the positions of horizontal pairs, and the second contains the positions of the vertical pairs:

```
With[{split = Partition[list, {2, 2}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}]},
  {Position[split[[All, ;; -2, 1]], {0, 1}],
   Position[Transpose[split, {1, 2, 4, 3}][[;; -2, All, 1]], {0, 1}]}]
freqs = Length /@ %
```

> {{{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {5, 2}, {5, 4}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 
>      3}, {4, 5}}}
>   {4, 5}

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are dealing with nonnegative integers only, then the following approach should work:

```
{
    Position[ListCorrelate[{{2, 1}}, list], 1],
    Position[ListCorrelate[{{2},{1}}, list], 1]
}
Length /@ %
```

> {{{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {5, 2}, {5, 4}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 3}, {4, 5}}}
>
> {4, 5}

Answer (score 4):

Using `SequencePosition` (new in 10.1)

```
f[s_][list_] :=
 Module[{x},
  x = Map[SequencePosition[#, s] &, list];
  x = MapIndexed[Thread[{#2[[1]], #1}] &] @ x;
  Join @@ Replace[x, {a_, {b_, _}} :> {a, b}, {2}]]

list = 
  {{0, 0, 0, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1}};

s = {0, 1};

{f[s] @ list, Reverse /@ f[s] @ Transpose @ list}
```

{{{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {5, 2}, {5, 4}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4,
3}, {4, 5}}}

```
Length /@ %
```

{4, 5}

```
s = {2, 2, 1};

{f[s] @ list, Reverse /@ f[s] @ Transpose @ list}
```

{{{3, 1}}, {}}

```
Length /@ %
```

{1, 0}

Comment: (+1) Nicely done, @eldo! :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Rows**

```
MapIndexed[Distribute[{#2,SequencePosition[#,{0,1}]},List]&,list]//Catenate

(* {{1,{3,4}},{2,{3,4}},{5,{2,3}},{5,{4,5}}} *)

Length@%

(* 4 *)
```

**Columns**

```
MapIndexed[Distribute[{#2,SequencePosition[ {0,1}]},List]&,Transpose@list]//Catenate

(* {{1,{1,2}},{2,{1,2}},{3,{2,3}},{3,{4,5}},{5,{4,5}}} *) 

Length@%

(* 5 *)
```

**Extract/Check**

*Rows*

```
list[[Sequence@@#]]&/@(MapIndexed[Distribute[{#2,
  SequencePosition[#,{0,1}]},List]&,list]//Catenate)

 (* {{0,1},{0,1},{0,1},{0,1}} *)
```

*Columns*

```
Transpose[list][[Sequence@@#]]&/@(MapIndexed[Distribute[{#2,
  SequencePosition[#,{0,1}]},List]&,Transpose@list]//Catenate)

(* {{0,1},{0,1},{0,1},{0,1},{0,1}} *)
```

Comment: +1 - much shorter than my solution :)

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{0, 0, 0, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 0, 0}, 
        {1, 1, 0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1}};
```

Using `Count`:

```
f = Total@(Count[Partition[#, 2, 1], {0, 1}] & /@ #) &;

f /@ {#, Transpose@#} &@list

(*{4, 5}*)
```

Or using `SequenceCases`:

```
f[l_] := Total[Count[{0, 1}]@SequenceCases[#, s : {0, 1} :> s] & /@ l]

f /@ {#, Transpose@#} &@list

(*{4, 5}*)
```

Comment: +1, nice alternatives if we only want to count

Answer (score 2):

Also:

```
list = {{0,0,0,1,2}, {1,1,0,1,1}, {2,2,1,0,0}, {1,1,0,2,0}, {0,0,1,0,1}};
seq = {0,1};
```

*Rows*

```
Position[Partition[#, {1, Length@seq}, 1], List@seq] &@list // {#, Length@#} &
```

> {{{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {5, 2}, {5, 4}}, 4}

*Columns*

```
Position[Partition[#, {Length@seq, 1}, 1], List/@seq] &@list // {#, Length@#} &
```

> {{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 3}, {4, 5}}, 5}

Comment: +1 Very nice, @vindobona!